# How to define cost function for custom nonlinear functions?

Tags: deep-learning, deep-neural-networks, logistic-regression

For logistic regression, the ***Cost*** function is defined as:
\begin{equation}
Cost(h_{\theta}(x)-y) = -ylog(h_{\theta}(x))-(1-y)log(1-h_{\theta}(x))
\end{equation}

I now have a nonlinear function
\begin{equation}
 h_{\theta}^{(i)}(x)=xe^{-j\theta_i|x|^2}
\end{equation}
where $i$ denotes the $i$th training sample. How should I define cost function for this particular nonlinear function?

Comment: Hi Yifan. I might be able to answer this question later. Meanwhile, if you need immediate help, you might want to ask the question also on https://stats.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Hi nbro, thank you very much for the suggestion~~ However I'll wait for your response~~ I'll ask there next time : )

Comment: Hi again~~ I would really like to ask if you could give me a hint on this problem~ Thank you so much

Comment: Hi Yifan! I am sorry I only answer now. It had been a while since I had worked with logistic regression, so I needed some time to review it. Have a look at [generalised linear models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_linear_model) (link function and prediction/mean function). In the usual case of logistic regression, the link function is the logarithm of the odds ratio, that is, it is $\ln \left( \frac{p}{1 - p} \right)$, because the mean function is $\frac{1}{1 + e^{-x^T \beta}}$. In your case, you have a different mean function, which will correspond to some link function.

Comment: Hi~~~ thank you so much for this. I'll have a deeper look into it and let you know~ Thank you so much for all the help!